# Getting data from php file in my Android java class using bufferreader

Tags: java, php, android

I am getting data from php file in android java class using

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
 InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));.
```

This code is in my php file is

```
echo "abc";
echo "xyz";
```

This is the code of my java file.

```
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        Complete_line = null;// Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            break;
        }
```

But when I read from Buffer reader it will read a whole one line, or it will print "line" string as "abcxyz". But I want them as two lines as they are two different lines in the PHP file.

Comment: in php, do `echo "abc\n";`

Comment: Posted this as an answer, please accept it since it worked

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, unless you seperate the 2 lines a a newline character `\n`, the two echos are the same. To seperate `echo`s into different lines, you need to end the strings with `\n`, like this:

```
echo "abc\n";
echo "xyz\n";
```